# Loop not displaying last record in datagridview | VB.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datagridview

Hello I am trying to populate a data grid view using for loop but it doesn't display the last record.

and it causes an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
> occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
> and less than the size of the collection.

here is my code so far

```
Dim undeclared As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Description, Area, RCNsqm, LVp, ELS, YrDep, RCN, Depreciation, NAV, LV FROM APRLandImprovementTabUndeclared WHERE RefNo = '" & MetroTextBox4.Text & "'", jonsqlcon)
Dim dsundeclared As New DataTable
undeclared.Fill(dsundeclared)
If dsundeclared.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To dsundeclared.Rows.Count - 1
        MetroGrid5.Rows.Item(i).Cells(0).Value = dsundeclared.Rows.Item(i).Item("Description").ToString
        MetroGrid5.Rows.Item(i).Cells(1).Value = dsundeclared.Rows.Item(i).Item("Area").ToString
        MetroGrid5.Rows.Item(i).Cells(2).Value = dsundeclared.Rows.Item(i).Item("RCNsqm").ToString
        MetroGrid5.Rows.Item(i).Cells(3).Value = dsundeclared.Rows.Item(i).Item("LVp").ToString
        MetroGrid5.Rows.Item(i).Cells(4).Value = dsundeclared.Rows.Item(i).Item("ELS").ToString
        MetroGrid5.Rows.Item(i).Cells(5).Value = dsundeclared.Rows.Item(i).Item("YrDep").ToString
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Why would you not just bind the `DataTable` to the grid? Creating rows manually like that makes little sense. If you were going to use a loop, at least make it a `For Each` loop. That would also negate the need for that `If` statement.

Comment: It wont trigger the cell value change that's why I am not using data bind

Comment: I just realised that you're updating existing rows rather than creating new ones. I'm not really sure what you're expecting but it seems clear that you haven't actually debugged your code properly, so you should do that now. You'll then be able to see and explain to us EXACTLY where and how the actual behaviour of the code differs from your expectations.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're creating a `DataSet` and then using the `DefaultView` of a `DataTable` within it. Just create a `DataTable` and use that `DataTable`. No `DataSet` and no `DefaultView`. Your code will become considerably more readable as a result.

Comment: One obvious issue with your code is the fact that you're trying to access an item beyond the bounds of the table. Arrays and collections in .NET are zero-based, so the first index is `0` and the last index is `Count - 1`. Your loop is going to `Count`, so the last iteration should throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I'm not sure how that could not be happening but you haven't indicated that it is, so who knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your code line for loop is :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dsundeclared.Tables(0).DefaultView.Count
```

you started loop with 0. but may be 0 is for caption ROW / Header ROW and actual data starts from ROW number 1. May be that is the problem.

and actually if that is the case your first record would not going to visible not the last.

and yes as per @jmcilhinney's comment loop should look like this

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dsundeclared.Tables(0).DefaultView.Count**-1**
```